# how to fetch data in Vuetable-2 from multiple controllers and show them in details row

Tags: vuejs2

I have laravel 5.8 api project I am using Vuetable-2 built with vuejs but I can not show data from many api url , example: I need to show the category in row and category items in row details , my categories in controller and items in another controller.
how to do it.?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all API data in different object variable and then use `object1.extend(object2)`

You can do something like below,

```
Object.extend = function(destination,source) {
    for (var property in source)
        destination[property] = source[property];
    return destination;
}
```

`property` will be the id to compare and merge data of 2 objects.

Hope this helps.